# Extract URLS with or without "#..." in them from text file

Tags: regex, url, python-3.x

***Disclaimer:*** I know that there are a lot of questions about this type of thing before, and if this is a dupe, please mark it or just give me the link & I can delete this post.

---

***Semi-Disclaimer***: I'm not familiar with regex, so I can't do this on my own :/

---

I have a file that would look something like this:

```
asd<a href="http://asd.asd.asd#asd">asd</a>
asd<a href="https://asd.asd.asd#asd">asd</a>
```

So many **asd**'s because I don't know if:

- `http` or `https`
- `www.` or something else
- `#something` or nothing

I want the script to take this file, say, input.txt, extract all the urls, **with the `#___`**, and then output, one per line, to another text file, say, output.txt.

For this example, the output would be:

```
http://asd.asd.asd#asd
https://asd.asd.asd#asd
```

Again, sorry if this is a duplicate and I just am not good at using Google, and, in advance, thank you :)

**Using Python 3**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<=href=")[^"]*#[^"]*(?=")
```

You can simply use this regex with `re.findall` and get the results.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/7

If `#` is optional use

```
(?<=href=")[^"]*(?=")
```

You can use it as

`f=open("input.txt","r")`

`print (re.findall(r'(?<=href=")[^"]*#[^"]*(?=")',f.read()))`

Comment: You have to make the '#'-char optional to make it correctly working, as OP has asked the '#something' to be optional: (?<=href=")[^"]*#?[^"]*(?=")

Comment: @vks This seems to work quite well. But as I said, I don't know `re` well, so how can I use this in code?

Comment: How can I loop through all? `for x in re.findall():` isn't working.

Comment: I want to output all results to a file, not just print. Additionally, I assume you meant `re.findall(r'(?<=href=")[^"]*#[^"]*(?=")',f.read())`... Having all double brackets causes issues, of course.

Comment: For some reason, this is just returning empty strings.

Comment: @Quelklef i used the same code that is posted above and it is working for me.what string are u providing to `re`.

Comment: Also, oddly enough, it works in the testing link provided.

Comment: @vks I know. The regex works in the test link you provided, though, so it should work still.

Comment: @vks With the input I tried, it didn't work. But that's beyond the point since I changed it, it printed, but then didn't regex correctly. [this](http://pastebin.com/Q33MvVMy) is what I tested with.

Comment: @vks Ugh... Unfortunately, N++ doesn't have a "remove all that isn't found in the search" option. If you can make me a regex that selects everything BUT the links, I could use that, though.

Comment: @vks not working. It's probably gonna be easiest to just fix the Python issues. Would you like files or raw text?

Comment: @vks It might, try making it for 3... This might be the issue.

Comment: @vks So, are you plannning on making one for py 3, or should I ask someone else?

Comment: @vks It's stuck loading for me, so this is the original script you madE?

Comment: @vks I don't remember there bring `print` or `print()` in the original script. If there's a new one, can you pastebin it, since that site won't load for me?

Comment: @vks What should it be encoded in? I can change this with N++, and it sounds like that will fix the issue.

Comment: @vks Also, I don't know if that _is_ the issue since `re.findall(r'(?<=href=")[^"]*#[^"]*(?=")','asdfg<a href="https://www.bla.com">asd</a>asd')` didn't work, either.

Comment: @vks no cigar, also see my other comment -- not working with a direct string instead of file opening

Comment: @vks I wasn't `print()`ing it is the issue. So it _is_ extracting URLs now, in the form of `['`URL`']`. Is there some way to remove the brackets & quotes?

Comment: @vks Oh, I did `list = re.findall()` and then `for value in list [do] print(value)`. The important part is that it's working. I'll mark you as answer and you may want to edit the post to include the part about needing `print()`. Thank you!

Comment: @vks This is working well so far, but I've noticed that it will take too much after the `#`. One could fix this via the knowledge that after the `#` is a word, then a space. The space and everything afterward should be exluded.

Comment: @Quelklef `(?<=href=")[^"]*#\S+`

Comment: @vks Hm... This seems to also take the `"<html><morehtml>` after it. I Guess the best way would actually be to end it at the quote. Were you doing that before?

Comment: @Quelklef yes it was the case before

Comment: @vks [here](http://pastebin.com/tVM2rgC6)'s the pastebin of the input that is not working correctly.

Comment: @Quelklef what do you mean by not correclty? `print re.findall(r'(?<=href=")[^" ]*#?[^" ]*',x)` with this i could find `81` links....r der more?

Comment: Oh, I was using `(?<=href=")[^"]*(?=")`. That one works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BeautifulSoup`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '''asd<a href="http://asd.asd.asd#asd">asd</a>
asd<a href="https://asd.asd.asd#asd">asd</a>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
print([i['href'] for i in soup.select('a') if '#' in i['href']])
```

Comment: `No module named 'bs4'`